# SQL Query - slow using replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is taking a long time, see below...

```
SELECT R.Email
      ,MAX(R.Id)
      ,MAX(R.Postcode)
FROM ParsedCandidates PC
    INNER JOIN Results R
        ON REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(R.[Resume], 'D:\documents\', '')
               ,'D:\CMT\Resumes\', '')
             , 'internal_', '')
           , 'monster_', '')
      = REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE(PC.[File], 'D:\documents\', '')
            ,'D:\CMT\Resumes\', '')
          ,'internal_', '')
        , 'monster_', '') 
WHERE CONTAINS(PC.ParsedCV, '"Marketing Executive"')
    AND R.Email IS NOT NULL
    AND R.Email <> ''
    AND R.Postcode IS NOT NULL
    AND R.Postcode <> ''
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM Candidates_Sourcing CS
                WHERE CS.Email = R.Email
                    AND CS.Email IS NOT NULL
                    AND CS.Email <> ''
               )
GROUP BY R.Email;
```

Both the candidates_sourcing table and the results table have many, many rows.

I know the replace function will be causing issues with sargability however I need to do it to ensure the match.

Any ideas how this can be improved

Comment: It will be, `REPLACE` makes the query non-SARGable, so the data engine has to perform a scan of the whole table. My guess is that you are using the `REPLACE` functions to remove the path and just return the file name? If so, you should really be storing the filename as a separate piece of information; either as a persisted computed column, or storing the path and filename as separate columns (and then indexing appropriately). Then you can simply use a clause like `R.ResumeFileName = PC.FileName`

Comment: Would a computer column mean that It can be indexed? wont the expense of doing the replace just be moved to the computed column and still be expensive?

Comment: Why I said a **persisted** computed column. They can be indexed, and (as the name suggests) the value is stored as a persisted value in the table.

Comment: @MatthewStott Yes - it is moving the cost. But you can take the hit when the columns are inserted/updated or you can take the hit **every time you run this query**. Which do you think is more expensive over time?

Comment: And just to add to @SMor's observation, you're not just shifting the workload, you're dividing it into tiny little pieces. One row's worth of `REPLACE` work will happen on every insert instead of thousands or millions of occurrences happening all at the same time during the execution of the query. Think of it as a divide and conquer approach, not a simple lift and shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create persisted columns on both tables and index those

```
ALTER TABLE Results ADD FixedPath AS REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 REPLACE([Resume], 'D:\documents\', '')
               ,'D:\CMT\Resumes\', '')
             , 'internal_', '')
           , 'monster_', '') PERSISTED

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixResults_FixedPath ON Results (FixedPath) INCLUDE (...) WHERE (...)
```

`INCLUDE` and possibly `WHERE` of your index will depend on your queries.

If you don't want to alter the table, you can create an indexed view on both these tables and then join the views.

```
CREATE VIEW v_Results 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT R.Id
--   , ... other columns ...
     , REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                   REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(R.[Resume], 'D:\documents\', '')
                   ,'D:\CMT\Resumes\', '')
                 , 'internal_', '')
               , 'monster_', '') AS FixedPath
  FROM dbo.Resume R
 WHERE R.Email IS NOT NULL
   AND R.Email <> ''
   AND R.Postcode IS NOT NULL
   AND R.Postcode <> ''
GO
```

However, the index has to be unique here.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ux ON dbo.v_Results (FixedPath, Id);
```

Having created both these views you can then join

```
SELECT ...
  FROM v_Results R WITH (NOEXPAND)
  JOIN v_ParsedCandidates PC WITH (NOEXPAND)
    ON R.FixedPath = PC.FixedPath
```

`NOEXPAND` hint prevents SQL Server from expanding the view into the underlying query. [See here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223412/is-using-indexed-view-with-no-expand-on-standard-edition-a-must).